# Position Call Out View Above Pin Swift ios MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I have a `MKAnnotation` with a custom CallOut View which is added in the following code :

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView,
             didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView)
{

    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
        return
    }


    let customAnnotation = view.annotation as! MyAnnotation

    if (applicable) {
        let calloutView = CustomCallout()
        var r : MKMapRect = largeMapView.visibleMapRect
        let p : MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(customAnnotation.coordinate)
        r.origin.x = p.x - r.size.width * 0.5
        r.origin.y = p.y - r.size.height * 0.75

        // 3

        calloutView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        calloutView.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        calloutView.clipsToBounds = true
        calloutView.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        let mapPointCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(p)
        let pointAsCGPoint : CGPoint = self.largeMapView.convertCoordinate(mapPointCoordinate, toPointToView: self.largeMapView)
        calloutView.frame = CGRectMake(pointAsCGPoint.x, pointAsCGPoint.y, viewWidth! * 0.6, (viewHeight! - 110) * 0.6)
        calloutView.addSubview(calloutView.imageView)
        view.addSubview(calloutView)


        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: (viewHeight! - 110) * 0.6))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: viewWidth! * 0.6))
        calloutView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView.imageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: calloutView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        calloutView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView.imageView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: calloutView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        calloutView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView.imageView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: calloutView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        calloutView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: calloutView.imageView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: calloutView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))


        largeMapView.setVisibleMapRect(r, animated: true)

    }


}
```

When the user presses the pin, I move the map to be horizontally centered and vertically in a `25-75` ratio to the pressed pin. Now I'm trying to center the `CustomCallOut` to be centered right above the pin, but no matter what I do it seems to erratically position itself on the screen.

Comment: Define "erratic"... is it left, right, upside down, sideways, etc?

Comment: That's the thing, sometimes its to the side of the pin, other times its above the pin, other times the pin is basically in the middle of the view... erratic is the only way I can define it

Comment: Is it perhaps where you are initially tapping before the pin is re-centered?

Comment: It is related to that, but not exactly, for example if the pin is in the upper section of the view before it is tapped, the callout would move down way below the new position of the pin, similarly if its in the lower half it would move up way too much.

Comment: It's strange you even need to do all that in the first place — `MKCoordinateRegion` generally will set the view up properly and display the label, callout, etc. accordingly.

Comment: That centers the pin in the middle of the screen, doesn't do anything for the CallOut though...maybe because it's custom and not the default one, not exactly sure?

Comment: I use it with MKPointAnnotation usually, so a callout might not work the same.

Comment: I'm following this : http://sweettutos.com/2016/03/16/how-to-completely-customise-your-map-annotations-callout-views/ He uses `calloutView.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width / 2, -calloutView.bounds.size.height*0.52)` to center the callOut (not sure why) but I'm guessing that only works if you don't move the map because it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using auto-layout, you don't have to adjust `frame` values, nor do you need to concern yourself with map coordinates. Just add constraints relative to the annotation view.

For example, this adds a blank gray callout view that is 60x30 right above the `MKPinAnnotationView`:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let calloutView = UIView()
    calloutView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    calloutView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    view.addSubview(calloutView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        calloutView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        calloutView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(60),
        calloutView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30),
        calloutView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor, constant: view.calloutOffset.x)
    ])
}
```

So, set the bottom anchor of the callout to be relative to the `MKAnnotationView`, and set the `centerX` to be offset by `calloutOffset`.

Clearly, you can set the contents and size of your callout to be whatever you want, but I hope this illustrates the way to get the custom callout view centered over the annotation view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped, didn't know it can be done so simply :)